# Checking session in Django custom user model

Tags: python, django

I am creating a custom user model, here's the code in models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contactnos = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

I have this line of code in views.py

```
def auth_view(request):
    try:
        m = Users.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        if m.password == request.POST['password']:
            request.session["id"] = m.id
            myid = request.session["id"]
            if myid == m.id:
                return render(request, "profile.html", {
                    'username': m,
                    'myid': myid
                })
            else:
                 HttpResponse("Session has expired. Log in again.")
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/invalid')
```

The code above can check if the user is in the database and able to redirect to profile page. What I want to achieve is if the user log out, the session key should expire or redirect to another page and not on the profile page.

And I want to ask, if it is really possible? Thanks.

Comment: `django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in` and `...user_logged_out` are signals you can intercept to create/delete such models about users. in logged in signal, you instantiate a model in DB and, in logged out signal, you delete such model

Comment: You should try to avoid creating your own authentication system and use the Django's built-in authentication. Also, it looks like you are either storing passwords in plaintext (big problem) or ```m.password == request.POST['password']``` will always fail because the value in the post isn't hashed.

Comment: Hmmn...how to do it? I just learn Django last week..sorry to bother you..can you provide some tutorial links about it..I've been searching it but somehow, all that I have found uses the default user model. Thanks

Comment: I will go further. You **must not** do this. You are storing passwords in the clear. There is absolutely no reason to do this. There is full documentation on the Django site on how to [create a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

Just create another view for log out.

```
def logout_view(request):
    try:
        del request.session['id']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
```

Comment: This doesn't work..I tried this before but when I logged out, I can still access the profile page. Thanks anyway.